# Calculate B&S breakeven given an option price

Tags: black-scholes

Is it possible, with some computationally fast method, to calculate breakeven stock price for B&S (given option price).

Approximation will also be good, but no minimization technique - pretty slow.

P.S. Sorry if I'm asking sheer stupidity.

Comment: The stock price today is what it is. There is no break even stock price. What you mean, I think, is break even stock price movement over the tenor of the option, i.e. break even volatility.

Comment: Let me explain myself better. Assume we established positive theta position t days ago. Nothing changed and we have a positive PL due to theta. What is the stock price where that PL=0?

Comment: So you are asking how much should the stock price change so that option price does not change, yes?